# Facebook Event Code

Tags: facebook, events

I have multiple Facebook Accounts that are using the same landing page. I know I can add multiple pixels to the same landing page and that they will fire and deliver me the correct results, my question is regarding the event code.

If I have one code on the landing page, will it be able to differentiate which ad account receives the correct data?

Comment: Don’t see how it should be able to do that. And I think somewhere in the Facebook docs it also mentions that trying to embed multiple pixels on a page is not recommended in the first place.

Comment: Hello - I spoke with a rep from their chat and they did mention it was fine to put multiple pixels on one landing page. I didn't think the event code would work like that. I appreciate your response :)@CBroe